# new features / enhancements for AppCompatActivity comparing with ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbaractivity, appcompatactivity

`AppCompatActivity` was added to the newest android-support-v7 library, based on some API documents that, it is supposed to replace the `ActionBarActivity`.

But both activities can do the same thing, then what's the reason. Does the `AppCompatActivity` bring any new features or enhancements ? or more-efficient execution, or other reasons that Im missing ?